# Как сохранить JWT в cookies используя node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

Всем привет, в двух словах, я нигде не нашел куски конкретного кода(на node js), который сохраняет JWT в cookies и потом при переходе на любую другую страницу происходить проверка этого самого JWT из cookies. Буду рад, если кто-нибудь поможет мне с этой дилеммой. JWT уже есть, все есть, осталось только засунуть это в куки и проверять на каждой странице для приватного доступа

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=nodejs+jwt+to+cookie

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39824342/4496422

Comment: https://dev.to/mr_cea/remaining-stateless-jwt-cookies-in-node-js-3lle